# Javascript value lost across scope

Tags: javascript, scope

This has been driving me mad for weeks.I have a variable data that I would like accessed at different parts of my program. Like such,

```
var data = [];

SomeNamespace.module.method(function(){
   data.push(['some data']);
});

// data is undefined here
```

But, it seems to be lost, possibly something to do with scope. How can I get around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: data shouldn't be `undefined` there, it should either have its data, or still be an empty array- depending on when `SomeNamespace.module.method` actually runs the function you passed in.

Comment: Pardon me, yes, it's still an empty array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That function is a callback, so data is not filled until that callback is ran.

So this:

```
var data = [];    
(function(){
   data.push(['some data']);
})();
data; // ['some data']
```

sets data, but:

```
var data = [];
var func = function() {
   data.push('values'); 
}
data; // [] - empty array
```

Comment: No, it's definitely still returning [] even after placing it in an anonymous self executing function.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't. Can you post the relative code, because something deeper is going on then.

Comment: I stand corrected; the callback function is asychronous, and doesn't assign when I was expecting it too. Thanks for the answer!